# jquery ajaxStart load function

Tags: jquery

Greetings I have a jquery load function below which works great. I'd like to add a ajaxStart function to my existing button to show a loading progress. Here is my code below. Any suggestions please. Thanks.
Here is the jquery section and button which is currently working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadQueryResults() {
$("#mydiv").load($("#region").val()+"commands.html");
return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to add the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by changing load method by ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
   url:$("#region").val()+"commands.html",
   type :"Get",
   dataType:"Html",
   beforeSend:function(){
      // show loading
    }
}).success(function(data){
   // hide loading
   $("#mydiv").html(data);
});
```